# Can I parent an object to follow a miximo animation?

Tags: animation, parent

I would like to parent or join the Object (yellow missile pod) to follow the animation movements of the mech (grey) which I animated (walk animation) through Miximo.  Is it possible?  Tried parenting but did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the object, shift select the mixamo armature, go to pose mode, select a bone you wish as parent, press Ctrl P - Bone.